# scalafmt class, methods params intendation

Tags: scala, scalafmt

Is it possible in scalafmt to set intendation to be like in intellij formatter so just after ending of `(`

ie:

```
case class SomeMessage(
                       id: UUID
                      )
```

I see only ability to setup tab numbers but its counted from line start not open bracket position

Answer (score 0):

By default `verticalMultiline.newlineAfterOpenParen` is set to  `false`. By adding the following lines to your scalafmt file you can override this config

```
continuationIndent.defnSite = 2
verticalMultiline.atDefnSite = true
verticalMultiline.arityThreshold = 2
verticalMultiline.newlineAfterOpenParen = true
```

Please refer [link](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html) for examples.

Comment: thanks, but still I I need to make intendation after "(", newlineAfterOpenParen created new line but still indent is counted from line start